# Displaying Things From 2 Different Tables With A Relation

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, database, relationship

I am trying to make a website that displays products from an sql database on asp.net page. So far I have 2 tables in my database.

table1: **Products**

```
ProductID , ProductName, KWH, ManufacturerID, ImageID
```

table2: **Image**

```
ImageID , Image
```

and a relation between them (`Image` is the parent table, and `Products` is the child table. The relation is from **ImageID** - **ImageID** ofc.) so that when I upload an image into the `Image` table it get's an ID which is also put in the `Products` table. Now how do I display a product with the right image on my asp.net page?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for helping you with issues on code **you have implemented**.  What have you tried so far?

Comment: Your child/parent relation doesn't seem right to me....you are saying 1 image can have many products, not one product can have many images?

Comment: No, 1 product will have 1 imageID?

Answer (score 0):

Check the tutorials on the internet. For example:
http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=129

In terms of the relation between Products table and Images table, read something about SQL Joins, i.e.:
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

I would also suggest some good book for ASP.NET.